# Javascript Sound input

Tags: javascript, audio

I was wondering if you could capture and process sound input with javascript? What I'm wanting to do is have javascript recognize certain tones and notes. There will be no background noise just the tones. I want the script to respond in such a way that  if the tone is say 1000hz it'll do one thing and if it's 2000hz it'll do another.

Comment: Your question is very similar to <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346399/sending-audio-data-to-javascript>

Comment: javascript doesn't have access to sound input. You would have more luck with flash, as it can do that, and manipulate sounds.

Answer (score 1):

No way i dont think. As you would need access to hardware (which i dont think JS can do)

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla has a Audio Data API you could use:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API

And you can use it with HTML 5 audio element.

http://weblog.bocoup.com/read-html5-audio-data-with-firefox-4
This should get you started.

However you didn't specify how you want the audio data to be entered. 
Recording through the mic directly?

Comment: I'm going to have a synth with different tones for different things. Although it would probably be easier to just have it all built into keyboard inputs.